# Rufus App - Constant Crashing

Tags: windows

When I open the Rufus app, without the usb plugged in, it works fine. When I plug in my USB, it immediately says "not responding". When I unplug my USB, it goes back to normal.  I'm just trying to copy a windows 11 disc image file onto my USB. Any advice?

Rufus version - 3.17.1846
operating system = Windows 10

Comment: Can you provide specifics? Is it a specific USB flash storage device or all flash storage devices? What version of Rufus? What version of Windows? Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: " Is it a specific USB flash storage device or all flash storage devices? "

Comment: And it must be said, again, why use a 3rd party tool when you can and should use the official Media Creation tool directly triggered by the ISO download (when done from a Windows machine)?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Sophos by any chance?

Sophos is [known](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/1597#issuecomment-728920973) to create extensive delays when Rufus is starting up, because it interferes with the ability of Windows application to enumerate USB media.

If not, you may want to check if you are running [any of the other software Rufus is known to be incompatible with](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Incompatible_Software).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Disable antivirus software like Sophos.
2. Manually format the USB drive.
3. Delete the Rufus and download it again.
4. Turn to use Microsoft's Media Creation Tool.